# (c++) trying to read numbers into array, getting junk numbers on output

Tags: c++, arrays

I've searched and searched this topic and still nothing so I'm resorting to this.

**NOTE: Can't use vectors at all**

So I'm trying to open up a text file in this program and read the numbers into an array. The program opens it up, and reads them (I'm assuming), but when I read the numbers the back, they are junk numbers. Not really sure where it went wrong, would appreciate some help. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void readNumbers(int numbers[]);

const int MAX_SIZE = 12;

int main()
{
    int numbers[MAX_SIZE];

    readNumbers(numbers);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << numbers[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

void readNumbers(int numbers[])
{
    int num = 0;

    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open("numbers.txt");

    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the file" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        inFile >> num;

        while(inFile)
        {
            int i = 0;
            numbers[i] += num;
            i++;
            inFile >> num;
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
}
```

Output:

```
1606416400
32767
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: What's in `numbers.txt`?

Comment: @Beta Each on their own line                                                                          47
89
65
36
12
25
17
8
62
10
87
62

Comment: You should use `while(inFile >> num)` to control the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array `numbers[]` is not initialized and you are incrementing nothing but garbage values `numbers[i] += num;`

hence it prints junk numbers.

If incrementing is important use:

```
int numbers[MAX_SIZE]={0}  //while declaration
```

If not:

```
numbers[i]=num   //inside while
```

Also `int i=0` should be outside while as i will always be `0` inside while.

Comment: I made the changes and now it just prints all 0's.

Comment: show the link to edited code in comment, you must did something wrong

Comment: @HOAX you should not edit the original question this will completely change the question and provided answers may seem wrong.Undo the orignal question.

Comment: This combined with another suggestion on here, kinda messed things up for me for a bit, but I figured it out and this helped the most. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The i variable is local to the loop. Try moving it outside:

```
    int i = 0;
    while(inFile)
    {
        numbers[i] += num;
        i++;
        inFile >> num;
    }
```

Comment: Nope this still didn't do it. Even attempted declaring the counter in the main and sending it. So lost at the moment.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `i` being local to the loop.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Damn, you're right, I was thinking of `for loops`. Sorry.

Comment: can anyone please tell me  , whats wrong with the $i being local in detail , i would be very thankful

Comment: @BhawinParkeria Having int i = 0 inside the loop will result in modifying numbers[0] over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

You're not initializing your `numbers` array, so it'll have garbage in it.  Why are you using `+=` when storing `num` in `numbers[i]`?  Shouldn't you be using an assignment there?

```
numbers[i] = num;
```

(And also, as previously mentioned, the `i` index needs to be declared outside the loop, otherwise you're always adding/assigning to the first element in numbers.)

Comment: I'm still not understanding this not initializing the array. I thought I did in the main, then passed it into the first function. Or do you mean giving a value to it?

Comment: @HOAX You declare it, but don't initialize it or assign it any values so it'll start with whatever values happen to be sitting on the unused stack space it is allocated at.

Answer (score 0):

fixed few errors in usage of array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

void readNumbers(std::string* numbers);

const int MAX_SIZE = 12;
int nSize = 0;

int main()
{
    std::string numbers[MAX_SIZE];
    readNumbers(numbers);

    for (int i = 0; i < nSize; i++)
    {
        cout << numbers[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

void readNumbers(std::string* numbers)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("numbers.txt");

    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the file" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        while(!inFile.eof())
        {
            char temp[100] = {0};
            inFile.getline(temp, 100);
            numbers[nSize++].assign(temp);
            if (nSize == MAX_SIZE) break;
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't compile. Xcode couldn't recognize the std::getline part. To be honest never used the "std::" and not really sure how to.

Comment: Answers that just consist of copy-and-paste of OP code with a couple minor edits are not very helpful as it is easy to miss one or more changes.  Explain what the changes are and why your are making them.  And in this case the code won't compile.